# Cookie not getting removed for certain environments

Tags: iis-6, session-cookies

I have an issue where the same code (web application) deployed to two isolated environments is behaving differently on "Logout".

The only apparent key difference is that Server1 is not secured protocol, therefore `http://myurl`. Server2 is secured protocol and is `https://myurl`.

These servers are both hosting the web application in II6 and I've already combed through the settings to find a difference but nothing sticks out. The web config doesn't have any special declarations of any sort.

The "Logout" mechanism is simple setting the expiration of the relevant cookie to a day prior and then redirecting back to the home page.

```
Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(Request.Cookies["MyCookie"]);
Response.Redirect("~/Folder/Homepage.aspx");
```

Does anyone have any theories on why the same code would behave differently on one server vs the other?

I have tried this with some of the popular browsers IE8/9, Chrome, Firefox with same results.  Even examining the cookie with the resource utility reveals that server1(http) disposes of the cookie correctly and server2(https) retains the cookie (examine the expire date reveals that the date was indeed set to yesterday but it still retaining it.)

Comment: Can you spot a difference in the `Set-Cookie` http header? (at both, login AND logout) because there might be 2 flags in, `secure` and `HttpOnly`, which might change the behaviour.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Would this be an IIS setting? I'll assume it is and go snoop around there.

Comment: I just googled arround and found similiar issues. You set it by `Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].httpOnly = true / false;`. But I really don't know if it has something to do with your problem. Another idea would be to set the cookie contents to empty, like set username='' etc, then you don't need to care if it is destroyed or not.

Comment: Let me chase that route real quick. Thanks for the input.  This is one of those things that just seems to evade common sense. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @DanFromGermany The httpOnly property seems to default to "false" so when examined by the dev tools in chrome I was able to see that server1 wasn't "httpOnly" and server2 likewise. I then used firefox and with the dev tools I was able to set this on the fly to be "httpOnly=true" on both server1 and server2 with no difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that because the login control that was generating the cookie was a reused control there was a hardcoded domain set. So I grabbed the cookie, modified the domain value, and set it to my current domain. Once this was done then I was able to expire the cookie correctly.